# timestamp "2022-01-02T12:30:30.471395746-06" is not recognized snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a timestamp that looks like this:

```
2022-01-02T12:30:30.471395746-06
```

I tried running the following code:

```sql
alter session set timestamp_input_format = 'AUTO';
select s.$1, s.$2, to_timestamp_tz(s.$3), s.$4, s.$5
     from @my_stage s limit 10;
```

This gives me an error saying:

```
Timestamp '2022-01-02T12:30:30.471395746-06' is not recognized
```

I also tried setting the format to

```
alter session set timestamp_input_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF9';
alter session set timestamp_output_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF9';
```

which did not work. Any suggestion would be appreicated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the timezone part at the end, it should be specified in the timestamp format as TZH in your case.

The following should work:

```
alter session set timestamp_input_format = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS.FF9TZH';
```

or

```
select to_timestamp_tz('2022-01-02T12:30:30.471395746-06', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS.FF9TZH');
```

Output:

> 2022-01-02T12:30:30.471395746-06:00